# Scheduled task creation in c++ works fine in almost all platforms except on Windows 7 32 bit for Standard User

Tags: c++, windows, windows-7, scheduled-tasks, 32-bit

This is a sample code which creates a test task in windows task scheduler. It works fine in Windows 7 64 bit (Admin + standard Account), also on Windows 8.1 32 bit (Admin + standard user). However, when I run same code on Windows 7 32 bit Administrator user it works but fails with Non-Admin (Standard) user account.

I searched and tried almost everything I could but nothing worked.

Basically, I get error here:

```
hr = pRootFolder->RegisterTaskDefinition(
        _bstr_t( wszTaskName ),
        pTask,
        TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE, 
        _variant_t(), 
        _variant_t(), 
        TASK_LOGON_INTERACTIVE_TOKEN,
        _variant_t(L""),
        &pRegisteredTask);
```

hr value returned (error code) : 80070005

Here is my code:

```
 /********************************************************************
 This sample schedules a task to start notepad.exe 1 minute from the
 time the task is registered. 
********************************************************************/

#define _WIN32_DCOM

#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <wincred.h>
//  Include the task header file.
#include <taskschd.h>
# pragma comment(lib, "taskschd.lib")
# pragma comment(lib, "comsupp.lib")
# pragma comment(lib, "credui.lib")
//
using namespace std;




int __cdecl wmain()
{
    int mystring;
    printf("started");
            cin>>mystring;

    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Initialize COM.
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        printf("\nCoInitializeEx failed: %x", hr );
        cin>>mystring;
        return 1;
    }

    //  Set general COM security levels.
    hr = CoInitializeSecurity(
        NULL,
        -1,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_PRIVACY,
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,
        NULL,
        0,
        NULL);

    if( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        printf("\nCoInitializeSecurity failed: %x", hr );
        CoUninitialize();
                cin>>mystring;

        return 1;
    }

    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Create a name for the task.
    LPCWSTR wszTaskName = L"Time Trigger Test Task";

    //  Get the windows directory and set the path to notepad.exe.
    wstring wstrExecutablePath = _wgetenv( L"WINDIR");
    wstrExecutablePath += L"\\SYSTEM32\\NOTEPAD.EXE";


    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Create an instance of the Task Service. 
    ITaskService *pService = NULL;
    hr = CoCreateInstance( CLSID_TaskScheduler,
                           NULL,
                           CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                           IID_ITaskService,
                           (void**)&pService );  
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("Failed to create an instance of ITaskService: %x", hr);
        CoUninitialize();
                cin>>mystring;

        return 1;
    }

    //  Connect to the task service.
    hr = pService->Connect(_variant_t(), _variant_t(),
        _variant_t(), _variant_t());
    if( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        printf("ITaskService::Connect failed: %x", hr );
        pService->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
                cin>>mystring;

        return 1;
    }

    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Get the pointer to the root task folder.  This folder will hold the
    //  new task that is registered.
    ITaskFolder *pRootFolder = NULL;
    hr = pService->GetFolder( _bstr_t( L"\\") , &pRootFolder );
    if( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        printf("Cannot get Root folder pointer: %x", hr );
        pService->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
                cin>>mystring;

        return 1;
    }

    //  If the same task exists, remove it.
    pRootFolder->DeleteTask( _bstr_t( wszTaskName), 0  );

    //  Create the task definition object to create the task.
    ITaskDefinition *pTask = NULL;
    hr = pService->NewTask( 0, &pTask );

    pService->Release();  // COM clean up.  Pointer is no longer used.
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("Failed to CoCreate an instance of the TaskService class: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
                cin>>mystring;

        return 1;
    }

    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Get the registration info for setting the identification.
    IRegistrationInfo *pRegInfo= NULL;
    hr = pTask->get_RegistrationInfo( &pRegInfo );
    if( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        printf("\nCannot get identification pointer: %x", hr );
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
                cin>>mystring;

        return 1;
    }

    hr = pRegInfo->put_Author( L"Author Name" );    
    pRegInfo->Release();  
    if( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        printf("\nCannot put identification info: %x", hr );
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
                cin>>mystring;

        return 1;
    }

    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Create the principal for the task - these credentials
    //  are overwritten with the credentials passed to RegisterTaskDefinition
    IPrincipal *pPrincipal = NULL;
    hr = pTask->get_Principal( &pPrincipal );
    if( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        printf("\nCannot get principal pointer: %x", hr );
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
                cin>>mystring;

        return 1;
    }

    //  Set up principal logon type to interactive logon
    hr = pPrincipal->put_LogonType( TASK_LOGON_INTERACTIVE_TOKEN );
    pPrincipal->Release();
    if( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        printf("\nCannot put principal info: %x", hr );
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
                cin>>mystring;

        return 1;
    }  



    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Create the settings for the task
    ITaskSettings *pSettings = NULL;
    hr = pTask->get_Settings( &pSettings );
    if( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        printf("\nCannot get settings pointer: %x", hr );
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
                cin>>mystring;

        return 1;
    }

    //  Set setting values for the task.  
    hr = pSettings->put_StartWhenAvailable(VARIANT_TRUE);
    pSettings->Release();
    if( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        printf("\nCannot put setting information: %x", hr );
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
                cin>>mystring;

        return 1;
    }

    // Set the idle settings for the task.
    IIdleSettings *pIdleSettings = NULL;
    hr = pSettings->get_IdleSettings( &pIdleSettings );
    if( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        printf("\nCannot get idle setting information: %x", hr );
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
                cin>>mystring;

        return 1;
    }

    hr = pIdleSettings->put_WaitTimeout(L"PT5M");
    pIdleSettings->Release();
    if( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        printf("\nCannot put idle setting information: %x", hr );
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
                cin>>mystring;

        return 1;
    }


    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Get the trigger collection to insert the time trigger.
    ITriggerCollection *pTriggerCollection = NULL;
    hr = pTask->get_Triggers( &pTriggerCollection );
    if( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        printf("\nCannot get trigger collection: %x", hr );
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
                cin>>mystring;

        return 1;
    }

    //  Add the time trigger to the task.
    ITrigger *pTrigger = NULL;    
    hr = pTriggerCollection->Create( TASK_TRIGGER_TIME, &pTrigger );     
    pTriggerCollection->Release();
    if( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        printf("\nCannot create trigger: %x", hr );
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
                cin>>mystring;

        return 1;
    }

    ITimeTrigger *pTimeTrigger = NULL;
    hr = pTrigger->QueryInterface( 
        IID_ITimeTrigger, (void**) &pTimeTrigger );
    pTrigger->Release();
    if( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        printf("\nQueryInterface call failed for ITimeTrigger: %x", hr );
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
                cin>>mystring;

        return 1;
    }

    hr = pTimeTrigger->put_Id( _bstr_t( L"Trigger1" ) );
    if( FAILED(hr) )
        printf("\nCannot put trigger ID: %x", hr);

    hr = pTimeTrigger->put_EndBoundary( _bstr_t(L"2015-05-02T08:00:00") );
    if( FAILED(hr) )
        printf("\nCannot put end boundary on trigger: %x", hr);

    //  Set the task to start at a certain time. The time 
    //  format should be YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS(+-)(timezone).
    //  For example, the start boundary below
    //  is January 1st 2005 at 12:05
    hr = pTimeTrigger->put_StartBoundary( _bstr_t(L"2005-01-01T12:05:00") );
    pTimeTrigger->Release();    
    if( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        printf("\nCannot add start boundary to trigger: %x", hr );
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
                cin>>mystring;

        return 1;
    }


    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Add an action to the task. This task will execute notepad.exe.     
    IActionCollection *pActionCollection = NULL;

    //  Get the task action collection pointer.
    hr = pTask->get_Actions( &pActionCollection );
    if( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        printf("\nCannot get Task collection pointer: %x", hr );
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
                cin>>mystring;

        return 1;
    }

    //  Create the action, specifying that it is an executable action.
    IAction *pAction = NULL;
    hr = pActionCollection->Create( TASK_ACTION_EXEC, &pAction );
    pActionCollection->Release();
    if( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        printf("\nCannot create the action: %x", hr );
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
                cin>>mystring;

        return 1;
    }

    IExecAction *pExecAction = NULL;
    //  QI for the executable task pointer.
    hr = pAction->QueryInterface( 
        IID_IExecAction, (void**) &pExecAction );
    pAction->Release();
    if( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        printf("\nQueryInterface call failed for IExecAction: %x", hr );
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  Set the path of the executable to notepad.exe.
    hr = pExecAction->put_Path( _bstr_t( wstrExecutablePath.c_str() ) );
    pExecAction->Release();
    if( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        printf("\nCannot put action path: %x", hr );
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
                cin>>mystring;

        return 1;
    }  

    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Save the task in the root folder.
    IRegisteredTask *pRegisteredTask = NULL;
    hr = pRootFolder->RegisterTaskDefinition(
            _bstr_t( wszTaskName ),
            pTask,
            TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE, 
            _variant_t(), 
            _variant_t(), 
            TASK_LOGON_INTERACTIVE_TOKEN,
            _variant_t(L""),
            &pRegisteredTask);
    if( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        printf("\nError saving the Task : %x", hr );
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
                cin>>mystring;

        return 1;
    }

    printf("\n Success! Task successfully registered. " );

    //  Clean up.
    pRootFolder->Release();
    pTask->Release();
    pRegisteredTask->Release();
    CoUninitialize();

    cin>>mystring;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is the error you wrote correct ? i was expecting 8 digits. the closest error I found was 80070057 wich says E_INVALIDARG.

Comment: or 80070005 = E_ACCESSDENIED.

Comment: sorry, you're correct, its 80070005 = E_ACCESSDENIED

Comment: well ,that explains it all. User have not enough privileges

Comment: But why it works in same scenario on win7 64 bit  ?

Comment: sorry ,don't know. can't help you there.

Comment: I found the reason why access-denied was returned. Bug appears if you already have task with same name on your system but created by a different user. Though you do not see this task in task scheduler, it's already there in the system and the logged in user being standard user he  don't have access to that task to delete or modify it.